# Can you remove all scoreboard tags from a player at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, to remove a tag from a player (or entity), you use the command

```
/scoreboard players tag <player> remove <tagName> [dataTag]
```

If I potentially have multiple scoreboard tags on a player, is there any way to remove them all with one command? As far as I can tell, there's no wildcard for the above command: using `*` for the `<tagName>` tries to remove a tag called `*`.

Comment: For entities you can set their data to `{Tags:[]}`, but I don't believe this is currently possible for players.

Comment: @colorfusion yeah, `/entitydata` doesn't let you change players.

Comment: @colorfusion I suppose, since I specifically asked "_is_ there any way", you fully answered the question, so if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this you have to remove them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a
```

or to remove all scoreboard tags to a specific player, use (X=playername):

```
/scoreboard players reset X
```

I hope this was helpful, as I've seen your question on here for quite some time. Have a good day!

Comment: That won't work. That resets *scores*. Tags aren't scores.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to use: /scoreboard player list and then remove each one by hand using: /scoreboard player remove X. X=scoreboard tag name